# How to run azure webjobs in parallel

Tags: threadpool, azure-webjobs

I have an azure webjob to be triggered manually.

Currently it is triggered via HTTP endpoint and seems to work.

The problem is when trying to run   parallel.

Then, I went the route of threading the parts of webjob but then I require an await which defeats the purpose.

The code in webjob is as follows:

```
ThreadRunner threadRunner = new ThreadRunner();
var threadRun = Task.Run(() => threadRunner.Run(...params...));
threadRun.ContinueWith(
    p => {
        if (p.Exception != null)
            p.Exception.Handle(x => {
                Console.WriteLine("Error occured");     
            });
});
```

There is no other code which is relevant, I am not using azure storage and queues and so there is no RunAndBlock basically.

Basically, the question is how to run webjobs multiple , when there is already one webjob running?

Comment: You are not asking a question per se. Can you rephrase to make it clearer what you are asking?

Comment: According to your code, it seems that run some code concurrently via multi-thread in WebJob. But for parallelism, concurrency & multi-process as you mentioned, they are different. Please explain your real purpose and what you want.

Comment: @peter aim is to be able to trigger that webjob again while the webjob is still processing a previous request.

Comment: @RohithNair So it means you want to invoke a webjob multiple times as multiple independent processes at the same time via HTTP endpoint of [WebJobs API](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs-API#invoke-a-triggered-job). Is it?

Comment: Yes. Exactly. Currently if one job is running, it will not allow next one to enter unless the first one is finished.